Google colab: ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
I am trying to use the logit lens model in this article: https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/AcKRB8wDpdaN6v6ru/interpreting-gpt-the-logit-lens ,
and the notebook https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MjdfK2srcerLrAJDRaJQKO0sUiZ-hQtA?usp=sharing#scrollTo=11X1oaLHxKMQ. However, I can't finish the environment setup. Always a error comes from  "%pip install git+https://github.com/finetuneanon/transformers/@gpt-neo-localattention".
And the error in detail:
Collecting tokenizers<0.11,>=0.10.1 (from transformers==4.6.0.dev0)
Using cached tokenizers-0.10.3.tar.gz (212 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.27 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from transformers==4.6.0.dev0) (4.66.4)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests->transformers==4.6.0.dev0) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests->transformers==4.6.0.dev0) (3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests->transformers==4.6.0.dev0) (2.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests->transformers==4.6.0.dev0) (2024.7.4)
Requirement already satisfied: click in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from sacremoses->transformers==4.6.0.dev0) (8.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from sacremoses->transformers==4.6.0.dev0) (1.4.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: transformers, tokenizers
Building wheel for transformers (pyproject.toml) ... done
Created wheel for transformers: filename=transformers-4.6.0.dev0-py3-none-any.whl size=2177639 sha256=c7fd38926bdf243c54728a1c93599317c109fcc4e7e6faa1236d939a14dee430
Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-__m6subf/wheels/be/65/32/6f5f754adfe11cfac7228866b9c1a142336f1b9611f3d90a22
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) ... error
ERROR: Failed building wheel for tokenizers
Successfully built transformers
Failed to build tokenizers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Could anyone help me out/
